# If git branch is deleted, why can that checkout?

Tags: github

If git branch is deleted, why can that checkout?

`git branch -d branch_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only deleting your local branch with one of the following commands:

```
git branch -d <branch_name>
git branch -D <branch_name>
```

In order to remove the branch from the remote (most likely named origin) you will have to use one of the following commands:

```
git push origin --delete <branch_name>
git push origin :<branch_name>
```